# Referencing an element rendered in ng-repeat loop returns 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with referencing an element rendered in ng-repeat loop. My code is:

```
         <div class="cars-container" data-ng-repeat="car in cars">
            <div data-ng-show="$index == 2">
               <div id="clock"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rental-car-box row">
            </div>
         </div>
```

There are 4 cars displayed on page. After the second one i want to show a div#clock and then do some operations on it in a controller.

The code In controller:

```
    $scope.cars = [];
```

cars is filled on page init with ajax call. When results come back I tried to watch the cars.length:

```
    $scope.$watch('cars.length', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if( newValue > 2 ) {
            console.log(angular.element('#clock').length);
        }
    });
```

but the console log shows 0.

Also tried: watching #clock:

```
   $scope.len = angular.element('#clock').length;
    $scope.$watch('len', function(n, o) {
        console.log(n, o)
    })
```

but no luck here either. It shows 0 all the time.

Any idea how this can be acomplished? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance 
Rafal

Comment: Try: `$scope.$watch('cars' ....)` or `$scope.$watch(function(){return angular.element('#clock').length;} ....)`

Comment: Thanks, that's it!